# WebClient:OpenRead Gives Unauthorized 401 Error

Tags: c#, webclient

Using C# I am trying to download an image with

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string url = "http://[user]:[password]@[IPAddress]:[Port]/image/Cam1";
    try
    {
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
        Bitmap bitmap; bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {...}
}
```

This throws the exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I also tried

client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential([user], [password]) with no success.

However, when I use the text of the url variable and paste it into a web browser it pulls the page/image up just fine.

Comment: Does the URL work from a fresh private browser window? I'm just wondering if the username/password needs to be explicitly used in a login first, before making the request, and the username/password isn't actually used in the image request

Comment: I did try this in an incognito window. If I don't use "[user]:[password]@" a popup window will be shown. When I cancel out of that window without entering anything (so no login information is stored) and then I do use "[user]:[password]@" then it works without prompting for login information.